# Google sheets script - mail onedit

Tags: google-docs

A couple people use one sheet and I want to be noticed by mail every time that an edit is made (at once user makes around 20 edits and I want receive only one mail).

I wrote a code:

```
var a;

function onOpen(){
  a = 0;
}

function onEdit(){
  a++;
}

function sendMail(){
 if(a > 0){
   GmailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com', 'aaa', 'sss ');
   a = 0;
  }
}
```

function onOpen is triggered by opening the document
function onEdit is triggered by any edit in a spreadsheet
function sendMail is triggered every 5min

I identified that function onOpen assignes 0 to var a only in the function and in sendMail var a is identified as NaN. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I tried to use built-in notifications, but for some reason it didn't work correctly. I received a lot of email notifications that were triggered for unknown reason (around 60 daily).

Anyone? Plsss...